# Create and maintain session in iphone

Tags: ipad, ios6

I am going to create an application in ipad in which I don't want to manage the session on server side to avoid the server calls.

So, how can I create and maintain the session in the application locally.

Comment: I'm uncertain as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish. If you offer a more detailed explanation, I'm sure someone would be happy to help.

Comment: Yes, Actually I am depending on server for handling the session in my application as they are sending me the session Id and with each request I am sending the session Id to check the session on server. Now I dont want to make ant server call for sessions and do it on the client side i.e. in iphone local application only..  So how can I implement this thing